# Is it possible to have database properties outside of any property file in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I want to ask is it possible to have database properties outside of any property file now I have database properties inside dbconfig.properties but I want to have it be supplied from outside passing as an argument for example. 
Is there any suggestion to have this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> **24.2 Accessing command line properties:**
>
> By default SpringApplication will convert any command line option
>   arguments (starting with ‘--’, e.g. --server.port=9000) to a property
>   and add it to the Spring Environment. As mentioned above, command line
>   properties always take precedence over other property sources.